# Beautiful soup find_all doesn't find CSS selector with multiple classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

On the website there is this `<a>` element

```
<a role="listitem" aria-level="1" href="https://www.rest.co.il" target="_blank" class="icon rest" title="this is main title" iconwidth="35px" aria-label="website connection" style="width: 30px; overflow: hidden;"></a>
```

So I use this code to catch the element
(note the **find_all** argument **a.icon.rest**)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.zap.co.il/models.aspx?sog=e-cellphone&pageinfo=1'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup  = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all("a.icon.rest"):
    x = link.get('href')
    print(x)
```

Which unfortunately returns nothing
although the beautiful soup documentation clearly says:

> If you want to search for tags that match two or more CSS classes, you
>   should use a CSS selector:
>
> css_soup.select("p.strikeout.body")
>   `returns: <p class="body strikeout"></p>`

So why isn't this working?
By the way, I'm using pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs you quoted explain, if you want to search for tags that match  two CSS classes, you have to use a CSS selector instead of a `find_all`. The example you quoted shows how to do that:

```
css_soup.select("p.strikeout.body")
```

But you didn't do that; you used `find_all` anyway, and of course it didn't work, because `find_all` doesn't take a CSS selector.

Change it to use `select`, which does take a CSS selector, and it will work.

Comment: It is hard not to get confused, since this line in the documentation uses `select()` in the middle of a chapter that explains about `find_all()`